# Run jQuery within PHP

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a form where I have the blockUI jQuery plugin getting called immediately when I press the submit button, which in turn causes a div with a "Loading.." animation to play in it.

The problem is that this Loading animation is triggered upon pressing the submit button, and if there are any validation issues with the form, if validation doesn't pass, the form actually doesn't submit but the loading div shows up anyways.

So, I think I need to trigger the blockUI only AFTER the form has passed validation.

I am using Wordpress plugin called Ninja Forms to submit and process the form. The documentation for Ninja Forms has this action which I think I need to utilize:  http://ninjaforms.com/documentation/developer-api/actions/ninja_forms_process/

I think I can use this ACTION to run blockUI only AFTER validation passes.

So I have this code below. But this doesn't seem to be working. The blockUI doesn't run at all now even if validation passes. So maybe I'm not triggering the jQuery to run correctly?

```
<?php

add_action( 'init', 'ninja_forms_register_example' );
function ninja_forms_register_example(){
add_action( 'ninja_forms_process', 'ninja_forms_example' );
}

function ninja_forms_example(){
global $ninja_forms_processing;

    echo "<script> $(document).ajaxStart(function(){ $.blockUI({ message: $('#rLo') }); });     </script> "; 
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you just show your HTML source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

add_action( 'init', 'ninja_forms_register_example' );
function ninja_forms_register_example(){
add_action( 'ninja_forms_process', 'ninja_forms_example' );
}

function ninja_forms_example(){
global $ninja_forms_processing;

    echo '<script> $(document).ajaxStart(function(){ $.blockUI({ message: $(\'#rLo\') }); });     </script> '; 
}

?>
```

You need to use single quote instead of double quote.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think you are correct there. It seems that this didn't help, so I may be incorrectly using this action. I'm following up with the plugin developer to see what they say. Thanks for your help good though good sir!